# Why does bindPopup not work inside my transparent Leaflet polygons?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

I am trying to display a popup from the attribute value of a geojson layer by calling the geojson file. However, the popup displayed on the edges of the boundaries of the polygons features only.

Here is the code:

```
var region = L.geoJson(region_data, {
    style: {
        fillColor: 'none',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'black'
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }

    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet (by default) takes the [`fillColor` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#path-fillcolor) given to any instances of `L.Path` and turns that into a [`fill` attribute of a SVG `<path>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill), as per [this fragment of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0f904a515879fcd08f69b7f51799ee7f18f23fd8/src/layer/vector/SVG.js#L169-L175):

```
    if (options.fill) {
        path.setAttribute('fill', options.fillColor || options.color);
        path.setAttribute('fill-opacity', options.fillOpacity);
        path.setAttribute('fill-rule', options.fillRule || 'evenodd');
    } else {
        path.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
    }
```

On the other hand, [as written in the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint), the `color` attribute can be `'none'`, in which case the web browser can **completely ignore** polygon fill - and that includes pointer hit detection, which in turn means mouse click events, which in turn means popup behaviour. In fact, that's the behaviour imposed by Leaflet when the [`fill` option of a `L.Path`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#path-fill) is set to `false` (as per the code snippet above).

If you want the polygon fill to fire pointer events (and the associated behaviour of triggering display of a bound popup), set the `fillColor` option to any other value. Remember that `'transparent'` is a valid colour value.

Comment: Now it works, many thanks @IvanSanchez